# SSO link for office 365 Calendar with OAuth token

Tags: ms-office, single-sign-on, office365, exchangewebservices

I have OAuth token generated from Azure ADFS.
I am using this to connect to office 365 to get users calendar events, which is all working fine.

Now i want to generate a link in my application, which when clicked by users should redirect to their office 365 calendar directly without prompting for any credentials.

Can this be done? 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the OAuth token represents a set of access rights granted by a user to your client at some point in the recent history and this does not mean that the user is still logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if i generate the token again to redirect the user to the office 365 portal if its expired.

Comment: The problem i have is how to send user directly to the office 365 portal calendar from a link in my application.